# WM_PAINT return 0 causing cpu usage 2%

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Im having a problem with my WM_Paint

If i make it return 0/1 it makes my cpu to stay around 1% even if the program is minimised.

My paint window is using OpenGL

If i break from WM_PAINT it causes drawing isues when resizing

```
case WM_PAINT:
{
    application->paint_window();
    return 0;
}

window = std::make_unique<platform::window>(
    L"Main window",
    CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
    1200, 600,
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW /*| WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN*/, 0,
    CS_OWNDC,
    this, process_message
);

while (::GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0) > 0)
{
    if (!::TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
    {
        ::TranslateMessage(&msg);
        ::DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

edit:
if i remove my function call in WM_PAINT my cpu goes up to 15%.
why does it go so high if im not doing anything.

Comment: *Only* 2%? Depending on what type of program you're making that's either nothing or very little.

Comment: around 2% while the window is minimised and shouldn't be doing anything, but for some reason is still getting WM_PAINT messages

Comment: There's a very simple solution to that: Don't paint when the window is minimized :). In your `WM_PAINT` handler, check if the window is minimized, and don't paint in that case.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i didnt think that WM_PAINT was ment to get called while minimised? also its getting called all the time, not just when the window needs to be painted.

Comment: if you don't call Begin/EndPaint() in your WM_PAINT event handler then the OS thinks the window did not get painted.  So it generates WM_PAINT again.  Your UI thread will burn 100% core.  So seeing 15% would be normal on a machine with 6 cores.  How calling your function could make that lower is not obvious but it probably does the right thing.  Use a profiler if you have no idea why your program requires too much cpu.  It doesn't btw.

Comment: The new question you edited in cannot be answered. We don't know, what `application->paint_window()` does. It likely just `Sleep()`s, when it detects that the window was minimized. Besides, don't alter your question to contain a new question. If you have a new question, click the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button.

Comment: all my paint window function does is draws a simple image on the screen with opengl context, there is no sleep function in there that would be silly.

Comment: That sounds like you have a blocking call in `paint_window()`, waiting for the GPU to finish rendering, thereby limiting the frequency at which you call `GetMessage`, and ultimately the rate at which `WM_PAINT` messages arrive. Without seeing that code, this is only speculation, though.

Comment: Downvoted because this question is unclear as we don't know what `application->paint_window()` is doing.

Answer (score 6):

As explained under [the WM_PAINT message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145137.aspx):

> The system sends this message to a window procedure when changes to the window have altered the content of the client area.

The system keeps an internal update region to determine, whether any parts of the window need painting. It is the application's responsibility to then validate the area it has painted to (either by a call to [BeginPaint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183362.aspx), [ValidateRect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145194.aspx), or [ValidateRgn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145195.aspx)).

Failing to validate the region that no longer needs to be updated will have the system re-generate a `WM_PAINT` message. That leads to the resource consumption you observe.

Comment: even if im drawing in a opengl context?

Comment: @ciyaso: The windowing subsystem doesn't know about your OpenGL context. It will maintain its own notion of an invalid region, that likely has no relation to your OpenGL context. If you don't want the windowing subsystem to keep generating `WM_PAINT` messages, you will have to play by its rules, and validate the invalid region.

Comment: @ciyaso: It is common, though. to use the window subsystem for visibility testing and update management, even with OpenGL applications. You'd have to translate the window's update region to the OpenGL scene, and pass that on to the rendering engine. It would still require that you then clear the invalid region as seen by the windowing system. It all depends on the characteristics of the application, whether this would be useful.